# redirect a live stream page to other pages in Flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm working on a project on an IoT device based on Flask and OpenCV. I found that when I visited the live stream page, there **was not any response** when I clicked the hyperlinks(these hyperlinks point to other pages) or submit a form.The only thing I can do is to go back. And then, sometimes the camera cannot be released properly and throws the errors

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
```

The code I use:

```
def gen_normal():
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while True:
      success, img = cap.read()
      _,frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
      yield (b'--frame\r\n'
       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
  cap.release()
```

Could anyone tell me how to submit a form on a live stream page? And how to make sure that the camera has been released properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get your local streaming IP via `ifconfig` (inet) and pass that to your code. 
`app.run(host='172.17.77.204', debug=True)`
Flask uses port 5000. If your code works fine you can see the stream on your web browser